# Infinite Integral inconsistency? (adaptIntegrate)

Tags: windows, r, infinite, integral

I used

```
library('cubature')
adaptIntegrate(doubleintegral, lowerLimit = c(-2.5, -2), upperLimit = c(0, 2), x=x,r=r,m=m,n=n)$integral
```

to integrate the following function:

```
doubleintegral <- function(y,x,r,n,m){
  max(((-y[1])^(n-1)*(y[2]-y[1])^(m-1)*exp((x[7]+x[4])*y[1]))*
  exp(-x[4]*y[2] - (r[v]-y[2]-x[5]*x[3]+0.5*x[6]^2*x[3])^2/(2*x[6]^2*x[3])),0)}
```

I used this Example Parameters

```
x <- numeric()
x[1] = 42
x[2] = 21
x[3] = 1
x[4] = 72.9
x[5] = 0.0332
x[6] = 0.0311
x[7] = 16.8
r <- numeric()
r = 0.0006
v = 1
r[v] = -0.036

w = 1
n = 2
i = 1
m = 2
```

I don't understand how the following output is possible:

```
> adaptIntegrate(doubleintegral, lowerLimit = c(-130, -4), upperLimit = c(0, 4), x=x,r=r,m=m,n=n)$integral
[1] 1.12184e-07
> adaptIntegrate(doubleintegral, lowerLimit = c(-2.5, -2), upperLimit = c(0, 2), x=x,r=r,m=m,n=n)$integral
[1] 2.516489e-07
```

By widening the limits i get a smaller value. I faced the same problem with the function "integrate" which i applied to another function. How is this possible?

Does someone has another idea for this doubleintegral?

thanks for your help!

Comment: i tried to plot your integrand on [-10, 10]x[-10,10], but the jungle of parameters forced me to give up. Can you come up with a more minimal example?

Comment: Here is the graph, please note the Integral boundaries. Btw didnt know this google function until now. [google](https://www.google.ch/search?q=double+integral+R+bounds+depending+on+variable&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=QvkIVPWCM4Lo7Aba3oDwCA#rls=org.mozilla:de:official&channel=fflb&q=%28%28-x%29^%282-1%29*%28y-x%29^%282-1%29*exp%28%2816.8%2B72.9%29*x%29%29*exp%28-72.9*y-+%28-0.036-y-0.0332*1%2B0.5*0.0311^2*1%29^2%2F%282*0.0311^2*1%29%29)